# Start stop demon with a user is not starting with given user

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix

I have requirement where I need to start a jar using "vsinv" user ( as a service )

I am using

> start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --make-pidfile --pidfile
>   /usr/local/vsinv/conf/vsinv.pid --chuid vsinv --background --exec
>   /usr/bin/java -- -jar /usr/local/vsinv/vsInv.jar
>   /usr/local/vsinv/conf/vs-system.properties

but this doesn't start at all but if I remove `chuid` and run below command it work ( but start as root user  or say current user )

> start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --make-pidfile --pidfile
>   /usr/local/vsinv/conf/vsinv.pid --background --exec /usr/bin/java --
>   -jar /usr/local/vsinv/vsInv.jar /usr/local/vsinv/conf/vs-system.properties

To start using vsinv user do vsinv user need to be have some configuration , am i missing something here

Comment: `sudo -u vsinv start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --make-pidfile --pidfile /usr/local/vsinv/conf/vsinv.pid --background --exec /usr/bin/java -- -jar /usr/local/vsinv/vsInv.jar /usr/local/vsinv/conf/vs-system.properties`

Comment: seem this is working , will test some more and let you know